# javax.enterprise.context.SessionScoped beans not found in httpsession

Tags: jsf-2, cdi

I have a jsf web applicationand used javax.enterprise.context.SessionScoped beans for CDI  beans and websphere server. I am assuming these beans will be added to httpsession and I could retrieve them to modify or utilized in other classes. But I could not get these beans from http session, they come as Null. If I change it to  javax.faces.bean.SessionScoped, it is appearing in session attributes. How to retrieve javax.enterprise.context.SessionScoped beans from http session or is there any difference how these were handled. Any help would be highly appreciated.

Let us say

```
Case-1:

@Named(value="webBean")
@SessionScoped //javax.enterprise.context.SessionScoped
public class WebBean{

}

I get null from httpsession.get("webBean") for the case-1.

Case-2:

@ManagedBean(value="webBean")
@SessionScoped //javax.faces.bean.SessionScoped
public class WebBean{

}

I get value from httpsession.get("webBean") for the case-2.
```

Thanks,

Hari

Comment: If you use `javax.enterprise.context.SessionScoped` with `@ManagedBean`, you are using a wrong tutorial....

Comment: I followed this tutorial link. 
 https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/tutorial/jsf-facelets003.htm.

Comment: Please see my code with comments for  @sessionscoped. I am not able to retrieve manually the bean which is of type CDI scope in httpsession.